# Make a derived object copy from pointer

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class A and B where B derives from A. And later I have a pointer A* which can point to an object class A or object class B. Now I'd like to copy this object under pointer without knowledge which object is pointed to by this pointer so if there is an A object then I'd like to copy an A object but if it's B then I'd like to copy B. I'd like to omit RTTI and dynamic casting. Do you have an idea how to do it? Or must I implement something like virtual cloning function and call it explicitly?

Comment: What have you tried... And what is going wrong? We work with code, we don't generate it.

Comment: " Or i must implement something like virtual cloning function and call it explicit?" Yes, that. (You can search for "clone" and "virtual copy constructor".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cloning virtual function is the most typical approach for this, for example as

```
class Base {
    public: virtual Base* clone() { return new Base(*this); }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public: virtual Base* clone() { return new Derived(*this); }
};
```

Sometimes however, when you have a pointer to `Derived` and you clone it, you suddenly have a pointer to `Base` while you know that it *is* derived. A down-cast is then needed, if you want to access `Derived`-specific members.

According to C++98-standard you can actually change the return type to the derived type, e.g.

```
class Base {
    public: virtual Base* clone() { return new Base(*this); }
};

class Derived : Base {
    public: virtual Derived* clone() { return new Derived(*this); } //will overload Base::clone
};
```

Comment: Not only "some" compilers, every Standard-compliant compiler. It's called "covariant return type" and has been incorporated in the C++98 Standard a long time ago. By the way you're missing a **public**, it should be `class Derived : public Base` (otherwise "the outside" can't convert a `Derived*` to `Base*`)

Comment: Oh, that information about covariant return type can be very useful, thanks!

Comment: @gx_ fixed as per your comment

Answer (score 0):

In the simple case of memberwise copy it seems strightforward:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    ~A(){}
    A() : _x('A') {}
    void foo() { cout << _x << endl; }   
protected:
    char _x;    
};

class B : public A{
public:
    ~B(){}
    B() { _x = 'B';}
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    A* b = new B();

    A* c(a);
    c->foo();  //A

    A* d(b);
    d->foo();   //B

    delete a,b;
}
```

Comment: You're just copying pointers. The OP wanted to copy _objects_ through pointers (and has already been answered). Besides, `delete a,b;` is horribly wrong, it's basically like `delete a;` then `b;` alone (statement with no effect), so you delete the `A` but not the `B` (`warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect` + [live example](http://ideone.com/0dV7V4)). And even if you fix that, you'll be deleting a `B` through a pointer-to-`A` and `A`'s destructor is not virtual, so it will call the wrong destructor. ("The amazing C++ genius", says your signature... you have a sense of humor.)

Comment: @gx_: Thanx, you have thought me alot.

Comment: My answer is wrong but I will not delete it as I found gx_ comment useful